# How to change the OpenERP column limit in tables?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, openerp-7

I have been working on `OpenERP-7` module development and I have come across a very strange issue when `adding new fields` to my model. It says that I have exceeded the `column limit` for the tables. Now I want to either change this limit or what? When I tried to reinstall after uninstalling the module, I am experiencing this issue :

```
OperationalError: tables can have at most 1600 columns
```

I have tried to remove the fields from my source code and updated the modules but still cant resolve it . I have come to know that there are certain columns in **PostgreSQL** which are hidden and we need to delete them to make things work.
Hopes for suggestions .Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to create a new table from your module or add new column in existing table ?? If you add new column in existing table then let us know that table name.

Comment: yes adding new columns (fields) to the existing table (class)

Comment: What is the table name ??